# Laravel Deloying file upload does not work on 000webhost

Tags: laravel

I have just uploaded a project to 000webhost, my problem is that the request of the inputs work fine, only the input "file" is not working when form submit, tt does not even request to input the file before uploading at the local server it works perfectly, please help me.

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post'))
        {

            if($request->color && $request->color != ''){ // Work fine
                $data['theme_color'] = $request->color;
            }

            if($request->copyright && $request->copyright != ''){ // Work fine
                $data['theme_copyright'] = $request->copyright;
            }

            if ($request->hasFile('logo')) // Not working
            {
                $file = $request->logo;
                $extension = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $logo  = md5_file($file).time().'.'.$extension;
                $request->logo->move('uploads/images', $logo);
                $data['theme_logo'] = $logo;
            }

        }
    }

 //view
<form action="{{ url('manage/setting/update') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 theme_color">
        <h5>Theme Color</h5>
        <div class="chosen_color" style="background-color: {{ $setting['theme_color'] }}"></div>
        <label for="upload-color">Chọn color ...</label>
        <input type="color" name="color" id="upload-color" value="{{ $setting['theme_color'] }}" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 theme_logo">
        <h5>Theme Logo</h5>
        <img src="{{ asset('uploads/images/'.$setting['theme_logo']) }}" width="200" height="100">
        <label for="upload-logo">Chose image ...</label>
        <input type="file" name="logo" id="upload-logo" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 theme_copyright">
        <h5>Theme Copyright</h5>
        <input type="text" name="copyright" class="form-control" style="width: 50%" value="{{ $setting['theme_copyright'] }}" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
        <a href="{{ url('manage/setting') }}" class="btn btn-default">Reset</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: can you share your view file code?

Comment: hi Ahmed Atoui, I have added the view file code, please review it